# How to formulate cumulative sum of LpVariable in Pulp Python

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, pulp, excel

I have a Multiple product LP optimization problem in which the product(B1,B2,D) will be received in variable quantity with respect to date column.

The Optimizer should LP variable Output as Assy Out B1, Assy Out B2, Assy Out D, Open Assy Line (Binary decision to produce or not in given date).

The target is to maximize the assembly output per day.

The constraints are material receipt for each date and not allowed to produce more than material available in each date

here is my data:
[image]

I used the code below:

```
dfs=dfs.set_index(dfs['t'])

x=np.arange(1,10)

Assy_B1=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_B1',x,0,None,'Integer')

Assy_B2=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_B2',x,0,None,'Integer')

Assy_D=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_D',x,0,None,'Integer')

Open_Line=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Open_Line',x,0,None,'Binary')

model=LpProblem('Assembly_Plan',LpMaximize)

model +=lpSum([ Assy_B1[t] + Assy_B2[t] + Assy_D[t] for t in x])

for i in x:
    model+=(Assy_B1[i]+Assy_B2[i]+Assy_D[i])<=(dfs.loc[i,'Max_Capacity ']*Open_Line[i])

    model+=lpSum(Assy_B1[i])<=dfs.loc[i,'INPUT B1']

    model+=lpSum(Assy_B2[i])<=dfs.loc[i,'INPUT B2']

    model+=lpSum(Assy_D[i])<=dfs.loc[i,'INPUT D']


model.solve()
```

The Model Solution is Optimal and output as below:

[image]

Everything is fine except the last date, the model should have capacity to produce 100 but utilized less (date 5/5/2022 cumulative produced is 60 and still 40 of model D can be produced on that day).

Similarly if the input material is available and capacity is less than cumulative material available the model should fit in next best available date for the same.

I am not able to fix this Constrain/Relaxation in Pulp.

Comment: I think providing a **reproducible** example would increase your chances of getting answers. I can't imagine anyone is willing to type out the data from your image in order to run your code snippet.

Comment: On 5/5, your constraint `model+=lpSum(Assy_D[i])<=dfs.loc[i,'INPUT D']` forces `Assy_D[i]` to be 0 since `dfs.loc[i,'INPUT D']` is 0 for that date. There isn't much point to the model as is though, since inputs have no weights, you could just select however much available INPUT and sum up to 100 if available. No ILP needed.

Comment: Hi Andy if i remove that constraint the model is filling 100 as output on non material available date also , example for Date 4/30 input of  is 0 but the model will fill value for Assy Out D on that date , so to restrict that i need to give this lock

Comment: There is no more input left over for 5/5, hence it does not sum up to 100. It uses up 20 and 40 for B1 and B2 respectively.

Comment: The Cumulative available qty of B2 and D is not utilized fully , example Input D cumulative 220 and Assy_Out D 100 only , at least in last day (5/5) there is a available capacity of 40 and it can be untilized

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example at this point -- I see you have an off by 1 difference in the two table screenshots you have provided. The second image 5/5 is a day behind the first image, which is what I have been referring to.

Comment: sorry its same date on both the screenshots , i placed wrong screenshot , consider the date is same no change

Comment: What is the use of Open_Line[i] variable? Also, you need to introduce inventory carry over variables for B1,B2,D to consider cumulative quantity.

Comment: Open_Lin[i] indicated the production happened on that particular , its binary and 0 value means no production on that date, thats why using (dfs.loc[i,'Max_Capacity ']*Open_Line[i]) in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can formulate/model the problem:
$$
\begin{align*}
x_{i,t} &\in R^{+} \text{ variable denoting amount of raw material $i$ processed/out in time $t$}\\
q_{i,t} &\in R^{+} \text{ variable denoting leftover raw material $i$ at end of time $t$}\\
I_{i,t} &\in R^{+} \text{ Parameter denoting amount of raw material $i$ that is provided in time $t$}
\end{align*}
$$
Quantity of raw material $i$ processed/out in time $t$ is less than available inventory & left over inventory needs to carry-forward
$$
\begin{align*}
x_{i,t}+q_{i,t} &= I_{i,t} \qquad \qquad \forall i,t | t= 0 \\
x_{i,t}+q_{i,t} &=  q_{i,t-1} + I_{i,t} \quad \forall i,t|t> 0
\end{align*}
$$
Limit on processing capacity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i} x_{i,t} &\le C^{\text{max}} \qquad \qquad  \forall t
\end{align*}
Objective is minimize left over of each week to get the behaviour required for total quantity processed across all materials & times
$$
\text{minimize} \sum_{i,t} q_{i,t}
$$
Note: As per your formulation, openLine[i] can always take 1 for each time period and binary is not needed as per requirement.

Comment: Wow perfectly working , Thanks anjikum , this is what i was expecting from this StackExchange community